# My 8600GT is outputting lowest video quality and strange colours

Tags: display, resolution, gpu, nvidia-geforce

I just got an 8600GT 256MB from a yard sale. I installed in it one of my desktops but the screen started out with large red pixels, then a grid-like thing of white. When it finally when it loaded into windows, it was displaying colours strangely, and at 8-bit with a resolution of 640x480 and I couldn't change it. I know its not the monitor because I tried it out with my other desktop, and i know its not the motherboard, because I tried another graphics card and it it worked fine, along with trying it in my other system. DO you know what is wrong with my GPU, if so, can i fix it?

Comment: Sounds like it has failed hence the reason you got it at a yard sale

Comment: One possibility, did you clean all the old drivers out with their respective tools (AMD and Nvidia have driver cleaning tools from their website). Although I don't think this is the fix, it's possible. The most likely case is the card is, like @Ramhound said, it has failed.

Comment: Hope you did not pay too much for it...

Answer (score 2):

On some nVidia GPUs, nVidia used a brittle material to fill between the bumps (the things that make contact with the circuit board) on the bottom of the GPU and the chip itself. As the GPU heats and cools, the brittle material cracks and eventually stops making reliable contact. This is called "bump underfill cracking".

This is the classic presentation of bump underfill cracking. The warmer the GPU gets, the better it will work because as it warms, the underfill expands and fills the cracks. So when you first power up, it may not work at all. As it warms up, it may work a bit better. But it will get worse and worse the more the GPU heats and cools as the underfill continues to crack.

Throw the card away.

Comment: @acejavelin yeah, i actually had no drivers on the computer i was using it on

Comment: No @moab, it was only $.25

Comment: So would you recommend reflowing the solder? @David Schwartz

Comment: @VapourKatz That won't help. The problem is not the connection to the bumps (which is the only thing you can reflow) but the connection between the bumps and the die (which you can't reflow because it's not solder).